# How to build a grafana panel plugin?

Tags: plugins, grafana

I am beginner in plugin development. i didn't get enough idea about plugin development from grafana tutorials,can u please give me a simple explanation about plugin development? from where we want to start ? how can pass live values ?

Answer (score 0):

There's a [documentation](https://grafana.com/tutorials/build-a-panel-plugin/) in grafana on how to build panels. You will need to have a knowledge in Typescript/React.

You may have to sign your custom plugin in the grafana configuration file. Refer [here](https://community.grafana.com/t/usigned-plugin-is-not-showing-in-gui-plugins/55256) and register also where are your plugins located.

You can try checking sample projects [here](https://github.com/grafana/grafana-starter-panel)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31352870)